# Given 2 functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ find a value where $g(x)$ divides $f(x)$ meaning $f(x) = 0 \mod g(x)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

**Problem**:

Given 2 functions $f(x) = 2^{p-1} + x*p$ and $g(x) = 2 * x * p + 1$ find the values where $f(x) = 0 \mod{g(x)}$, where $p$ is a prime number and $x$ is a non negative integer in the range $1,2,3,4,5,6... \frac{2^{p-1} - 1}{p}$. In these examples the $p$ is fixed a priori, so it constitute a constant value.

**Context**:

I'm currently trying to come up with an efficient algorithm to determine when the function $g(x)$ divides $f(x)$ at the point x. In other words have a $f(x) = 0 \mod g(x)$.

**For example**:

If we set $p = 11$ then we have:

- $f(x) = 2^{10} + x * 11$
- $g(x) = 2 * x * 11 + 1$

So for $x = 1$ we have:

- $f(1) = 1024 + 11  = 1035$
- $g(1) = 2 * 1 * 11 + 1 = 23$

Then:

- $ f(1) = 0 \mod g(1) $
- $1035 = 0 \mod 23$

If $x = 2$ we have:

- $f(2) = 2^{10} + 2 * 11 = 1046$
- $g(2) = 2 * 2 * 11 + 1 = 45$

Finally:

- $ f(2) = 11 \mod g(2) $
- $1046 = 11 \mod 45$

And so on ... **However, It doesn't matter how many divisor f(x) has I just need to know if it has any**

So the set of values where $f(x) = 0 \mod g(x) = {23, ...}$

I don't really know how modular arithmetics work for functions, or if this is even possible. I have been looking for examples online but unfortunately, as soon as I put mod and function in a sentence the search engine comes up with something different.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you very much for the comments, I will edit the problem according to the rules!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{g(x)} \; \Rightarrow \; 2f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{g(x)} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Thus,

$$2^p + 2xp \equiv 2^p + (2xp + 1) - 1 \equiv 2^p - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{g(x)} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

With $p$ being a prime number, $2^p - 1$ is called a Mersenne number. When it's also a prime number, it's called a [Mersenne prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime). The [Lucas-Lehmer primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) can relatively efficiently check if very large Mersenne numbers are prime, which is why the currently largest known primes are all Mersenne primes. Regarding checking for factors, I would suggest first checking against the [List of known Mersenne primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#List_of_known_Mersenne_primes) since, if it's in the list, then $x$ is the last value, i.e., $x = \frac{2^{p-1} - 1}{p}$. Also, an answer at [How to check if number is a Mersenne prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554175/how-to-check-if-number-is-a-mersenne-prime) has links to $2$ appropriate OEIS pages and a C# code sample with the values that fit into an unsigned integer in it. Otherwise, there are a few simple things you can do to simplify your checks, such as described at [Factors of a Mersenne number](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factors_of_a_Mersenne_number).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I found it very useful. However, I also wanted to know if there is some theory around how to resolve the $f(x) \mod g(x) $ So I want to know how a change in x affects the modulus of the function. Something like the derivatives that is the rate of change of the area under the curve. So I was wondering if you have a clue in this direction?

Comment: @Erick84mm You're welcome for the help. Re: what you're asking about in your comment, if I understand correctly, I don't believe there's any general method to determine the result of an arbitrary $f(x)$ function modulo an arbitrary $g(x)$ function as $x$ changes. Derivatives use continuity for rates of change. However, even a change by $1$ in $g(x)$ can possibly have a large effect on the result of $f(x)$ modulo that value. Nonetheless, there are a few special cases such as $f(x)$ & $g(x)$ being polynomials, with $f(x)$'s degree being larger, as you can then divide $g(x)$ into $f(x)$ & use ...

Comment: @Erick84mm (cont.) the resulting smaller degree polynomial. However, number theory isn't my area of expertise, so I may be missing something fairly useful, but in any case, comments aren't the proper place to discuss the topic. If you're particularly interested, I suggest you post another question where you clearly explain what you're asking about, plus what you've done so far, including what I've written here if you wish to use it. One last thing, if you believe my answer has satisfactorily resolved your posted question, please accept it by clicking on the check mark on the left. Thanks.

Comment: Ah! I understand I will search for those special cases that you describe in the number theory field. Again thank you very much for your help!. This answers the questions so I will mark it as resolved and once I find more insides in the topic I will update the post. Thanks again!